# If library is not visible to you why you see the automatic link in current navigation?

Tags: permissions, current-navigation

I used to remember that if you stop inheriting permissions from top and display automatic link in current navigation of a library, the users that have been removed should NOT see the library link at all. Now they can see the library link but when they click on it they see empty library. I expected the access denied page but no, just the library without any content (they can see however all metadata columns).

Am I remembering wrong or something has changed? The only way to 'hide' the URL is to use Audience targeting in Settings - Navigation?

I am using a classic site.

Answer (score 1):

Check the user's permissions. Do they still have the "Limited Access" permission? This would let them see the library page, but not the content of the library.

Go the the Library Settings page for the library, click Library Permissions and the click Check Permissions.

[image]

Comment: yes they have limited, what can i do to avoid that they have limited?

Comment: I also add that they have limited and Given through the "Style Resource Readers" group. I thought that this style resource readers was the group they needed to get at least the 'access denied' page